# Verificar se data é valida na procedure MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, stored-procedures

Boa tarde programadores, estou com um probleminha na procedure onde preciso inicialmente imprimir todas as datas do mês, criei um laço até o dia 31, mas tem mês que é menos dias que isso dai dá erro, como verificar na procedure se da data é valida?

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE VisaoEvolucaoSemanal(dataIn date)
BEGIN
DECLARE dia decimal(2);
DECLARE mes varchar(10);
DECLARE ano varchar(10);
DECLARE media decimal(10,2);
DECLARE dataBusca date;
DECLARE datasaida date;

set dia = 00;
set mes = month (dataIn);
set ano = year(dataIn);

loop_data: LOOP
    SET dia = dia + 01;

    set datasaida = CONCAT(ano,'-',mes,'-',dia);

    select datasaida;

    IF dia > 31 THEN
        LEAVE loop_data;
    END IF;
END LOOP loop_data;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Qual a sua versão do `MySQL`?

Comment: a versão do MySQL é 5.7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função `WEEK` para verificar se um texto de data é válido. Montei abaixo um exemplo.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE dias (
  descricao VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO dias(descricao)
          VALUES('2019-02-28'),
                ('2019-02-29');
```

---

**Query**

```
SELECT d.*,
       CASE 
         WHEN WEEK(d.descricao) IS NULL THEN 'INVÁLIDA'
         ELSE 'VÁLIDA'
       END AS data_valida
  FROM dias d;
```

---

**Resultado**

```
| descricao  | data_valida |
| ---------- | ----------- |
| 2019-02-28 | VÁLIDA      |
| 2019-02-29 | INVÁLIDA    |
```

---

Veja funcionando no [**DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eXe1ffcRdQugbujFsMNBi7/0)

Comment: Vou testar quando chegar em casa, obrigado!

Comment: este código me serviu bem 
IF datasaida = LAST_DAY(datasaida) THEN
        LEAVE loop_data;
    END IF;

Comment: @MichelDiniz sim, mas você perguntou como verificar se a data é válida e não como achar o final do mês.

Comment: É vdd, o código funciona, só mudei a lógica para sempre que a data do loop foi igual ao ultimo dia do mês ele para, obrigado pela ajuda!